# Fetching Keycloak password in web application

Tags: web-applications, keycloak

I have a web application where the UI and services are running on different tomcat servers.
I have to integrate my application with Keycloak which I could do and I am now able to login.

I want the password entered by the user for logging into the keycloak in the UI application. Is this possible?

Comment: No,Keycloak wont pass password it always give you a token after successful login ,that token can be used.

Comment: Thank you. So My Web UI has users configured in the Active Directory and I have integrated the active directory with the Keycloak to import users and groups from active directory. But for some requests, the services which runs on a different tomcat server also needs to connect to Active directory. Before I integrated Keycloak with my UI application, the username and password was being passed to service to connect to AD. If the keycloak does not give the password, I guess I cannot connect to AD form the services

Comment: Do you mean one Service Going from the keycloak and other service without keycloak?